# How to open a link on a LWC Carousel in a new tab?

Tags: lightning-web-components, images, hyperlink, carousel

I am quite new to Salesforce and web dev so please bear with me.

I have a lightning web component with a lightning-carousel and multiple carousel-images.
Each of the images also has a link to a different site and these links should open in a new tab. As far as I can tell the carousel-image component lacks a standard way of doing this.

example HTML:

```
<lightning-carousel>
  <lightning-carousel-image
    src = {image1}
    header = "title1"
    href = "https://www.google.com"
  >
  </lightning-carousel-image>
  <lightning-carousel-image
    src = {image2}
    header = "title2"               
    href = "https://www.salesforce.com" 
  >
  </lightning-carousel-image>
</lightning-carousel>
```

I already tried a few things, but nothing has worked so far.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use this alternative method where you can add onclick method and handle that method in JS and redirect accordingly.

You can see in this

> [DEMO](https://studio.webcomponents.dev/edit/bO7X2yJAOIYB5fTznaFs/src/app.html?p=stories)

Comment: Thanks for your help